# How can I create this circles for my flutter UI?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create those blue circles (you can see them on the picture), the app UI design was created with Figma.

I don't even know how to start, I'm new at flutter

Any ideas or tips?

[image: Screenshot of Figma design]

Comment: Are these intended to be clickable? Are they radio buttons, or indicating the state of some page/view, or something else?

Comment: @Jaked222 No, it won't be clickable, are intended to indicate a state as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start learning from [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout).
There are many ways to do this. I am using Container with decoration

```dart
Container(
  height: 70,
  width: 70,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), //spacing using padding
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.blue),
  ),
  child: const Material( //inner circle
    color: Colors.green,
    shape: CircleBorder(),
  ),
)
```

More about  [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).